# i want to create scrollable video using Exoplayer

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer2.x

I have to do is if the video height is large then add runtime scroll vertically  and
if the video width is large then add runtime scroll horizontally then after cut the video with fix height, width and 1:1 ratio without loosing quality of video.

I am using Exoplayer for video. please help me and Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thats not Scroll able Video player i think its the container which is scrollbale . The image you have added is of multi window mode . have you try adding ExoPlayer inside ScrollView ?

Comment: but I add in ExoPlayer inside Scrollview then when video play that time scrollview working?

Comment: I am not sure that's why I asked.  Why don't you give it try . There could be problem with touch actions .

Comment: let be I am try